# How to separate my output by comma?

Tags: r, output

```
km<-kmeans(iris,3)
scorekm<-
function(km, x,...)
{
    args<-list(x,...)
    result=NULL
    for(i in seq(from=1,to=nargs()-1,by=4))
        {
    data<-matrix(c(args[[i]],args[[i+1]],args[[i+2]],args[[i+3]]),nrow=1)
    k <- nrow(km$centers)
    d <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(km$centers, data)))[-(1:k),1:k]
    d <- matrix(d,nrow=1)
    category<- apply(d,1,which.min)
    result<-cbind(category,result)
}
    return(result)
}
```

Now, my output is like this:

```
> scorekm(km,5.9,3.0,5.1,1.8,5.1,3.8,1.6,0.2)
 category category category
>[1,]        1        2
```

How can I change it to be like this:
    `>[1,]     1,2`

Output is separated by comma.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: I am sorry, that doesn't make sense. It's of course possible to use `paste` for this, but your boss probably wants to use the output somehow. To have the data like this makes only sense for output, since it is pretty much unusable in R. And that probably means that you are looking for `write.csv` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

as Roland asked, why is relevant, as we don't know how you wish to use your output. But this should return **"result"** as a character string with a comma. Just change the line *result<-cbind(category, result)* with this **result<-paste(category, ",", result, sep="")**. Hope this helps.

Greetins, Ben

Comment: It's not that satisfying.Because there will be a comma at the end of of output.

Comment: Can I restore all the output in a character and then split them by comma?

Comment: with this little script, it looks as such:
> a<-1
> b<-2
> c(paste(a, ",", b, sep=""))
>[1] "1,2"
where do you have a comma too?

Comment: But for me.If I input 2 datasets just like this  >scorekm(km,5.1,4.9,3.2,0.1,5.1,4.6,3.2,0.2)
It shows like this   >[1] "1,1,"

Comment: ok, try this. reuse your result with cbind() then add this line result<-paste(result[1:length(result)], sep="", collapse=",")